# Git global ignore not working

Tags: git

I've created the file `.gitignore_global` and put it in my git install directory. When I run the command:

```
git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore
```

the rules in the ignore file do not get applied to my commits.

When I rename the file `.gitignore` and put it in my project root, the rules do apply.

What is wrong here?

Comment: @Jarrod ` ~/.gitignore_global` was what the OP meant and just a typo in the post, although he accepted my answer, so your edit isn't good

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Global Git ignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335420/global-git-ignore)

Comment: I landed upon question because it was not working for me too. My problem was writing `core.excludesfile` instead of `core.excludesFile` with a small F. Hope this helps anyone new who runs into a similar situation

Comment: see video here https://youtu.be/3LYBdd3RGKs

Answer (score 221, accepted):

Maybe you [need to do](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-coreexcludesFile):

```
git config --global core.excludesFile ~/.gitignore_global
```

And to have some coffee.

Comment: Sorry that's what I meant. The one I copied was just messing about to see what worked.

Comment: True for coffee and teeth. Are you sure .gitignore_global is in your $HOME? you say you installed it in git install directory?

Comment: any idea why it still not work here? I got a .7z file that I want to skip; I added these rules: https://gist.github.com/octocat/9257657; and after I change the file, it still gets versioned on .git :(

Comment: My .7z file was already added to .git repo; I had to `git rm` (had to backup before it), so the file begins being ignored!

Comment: Yes, `gitignore` file only works for untracked files, not for those which got added before

Comment: I need some coffee too :D

Comment: Try to just execute `git config --global core.excludesfile` and see which file got printed out, then go and edit that file, this way worked out for me. I guess the second file is the one you want to append for ignoring.

Comment: Another thing i just noticed was the pattern of the line in the .gitignore_global file must match the path from the main directory of the project EXACTLY. For example, if the project name is myProject, which generates SQL code in myProject/sql/init, and you want to ignore myProject/sql/init/*.sql the entry must be */sql/init/. Similarly, for generated DAO/DTO code in myProject/msg/dao/ and myProject/dao, there must be two entries to catch ALL files in dao subdirectories - */*/dao/ and */dao/ must be added.

Comment: Coffee did the trick and helped me realize I had misspelled my path, as well.

Answer (score 121):

Thought I would chip in on this. There is another reason why the global ignore file appears not to be working. It's something that I don't think has been covered in earlier answers. It's so blindingly obvious that - *of course* - it's very easy to miss.

It is, that git **will only ignore new files**. If the file is already being tracked by git, then of course git will not ignore it! So whatever patterns in any `gitignore` or `exclude` file **do not apply**.

That makes sense. Why would git want to ignore modifications to files it is already tracking? If the file is to be ignored, you must first tell git not to track it, then git ignore it as described in the manual. For info on how to untrack files, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936249/removing-a-file-from-git-source-control-but-not-from-the-source).

This all leads me to ask, is it possible to ignore changes to tracked files? Again, git delivers. This answer; [Git: Ignore tracked files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10755655/git-ignore-tracked-files) gives us the command (replace `file` with the file you want to ignore):

`git update-index --assume-unchanged file`

Finally, here's some additional info on debugging git ignore.

The [gitignore(5) Manual Page](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) tells us:

> Patterns which a user wants Git to ignore in all situations (e.g., backup or temporary files generated by the user's editor of choice) generally go into a file specified by core.excludesfile in the user's ~/.gitconfig. Its default value is $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/ignore. If $XDG_CONFIG_HOME is either not set or empty, $HOME/.config/git/ignore is used instead.

So, this is new and replaces the previous `~/.gitignore_global` mentioned previously.

Next, and this is really useful, is that as of 1.8.2, we now have some excellent debugging tools. Have a look at:

[Git Learns to Ignore Better - New in 1.8.2](http://stacktoheap.com/blog/2013/03/14/git-learns-to-ignore-better-new-in-1-8-2/)

This shows how to use the new `check-ignore` flag to verify that git is successfully ignoring your patterns, e.g.

`git check-ignore bin/a.dll --verbose`

Comment: I did `git check-ignore .` and it said unable to access ''C:\Users\...\.gitignore''. That is when I realized I had to remove the single inverted commas. I removed them by editing ~\.gitconfig

Comment: Do note that even though this works, there's a huge problem with this. Say you modified your file as needed and hold them with this command, then you `git stash` your changes for all files, and the files on hold will get stashed. When you do `git stash pop`, these files won't get recovered. So you effectively lost your changes and you have to modify those files again.

Comment: Great, thanks, "update-index" fixed it for me. :)
Actually to me it was not, and still is not, an "obvious" thing at all.

Answer (score 19):

I found that when I had defined the `global core.excludesfile` like this:

```
git config --global core.excludesfile $HOME/.config/git/ignore
```

it didn't work. Changing it to not use the `$HOME` variable, like this:

```
git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.config/git/ignore
```

it immediately started working. Hope this helps someone else.

FYI:

```
$ git --version
git version 1.7.10.2 (Apple Git-33)
```

Comment: I observed this too. I skimmed the documentation but didn't find anything:  In addition to .gitignore (per-directory) and .git/info/exclude, git looks into this file for patterns of files which are not meant to be tracked. "~/" is expanded to the value of $HOME and "~user/" to the specified user’s home directory.

Comment: This is the fix

Comment: Hadn't realised this, cheers!

Answer (score 11):

Note: starting [git1.7.12 (August 2012)](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kernel/1335335):

> The value of:
>
> - `core.attributesfile` defaults to $HOME/.config/git/attributes and
> - `core.excludesfile` defaults to    `$HOME/.config/git/ignore` respectively when these files exist.

So if you create a `$HOME/.config/git/attributes` file, you don't even have to set your `core.excludesfile` setting.

Answer (score 4):

The file must be in your home directory. On windows, it usually means:
    C:\documents and settings\[user].

On linux it is:
    /home/[user]

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem because I had initially called 'git config core.excludefiles'  without --global and with a wrong value, and hence it had stored the property locally. Looks like the local property hid the global one (which had the correct value), completely ignoring it.

Comment: This was my issue as well. Took a bit to find 

Comment: Me too. When debugging I did `git config core.excludesfile .gitignore` inside a repository. Had to go inside `.git/config` and remove the [core]/excludesfile line to make it work again.

Comment: @YuriGhensev thanks, I was going crazy with this, your comment was the way I fixed my problem

Answer (score 3):

Also I had a funny thing with encoding of this file. Somehow my Windows 10 (with Powershell) created the file with the encoding "UTF-16 LE" and somehow Git couldn't handle this. When I change the encoding to a much more sensible value of literally anything else it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Adding another thing ppl might have missed, or at least where I went wrong.

I made the mistake of not copy-pasting the command and I spelled
`excludefile` (wrong)
instead of
`excludesfile` (right)
and lost definitely half an hour or so before I reevaluated the spelling, thinking it was something else.

You don't get a warning or error for setting an option that is not a valid option. You do get a warning/error message if the syntax is invalid, which is why I wrongly assumed that a spelling mistake would be caught the same way.

Answer (score 2):

Another reason a global git ignore may not be working: invisible characters in the path.

I only found out this was my problem when pasting the warning message from [git-check-ignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore) into the address bar of Chrome, where it *luckily* became visible:

[image]

(It wasn't visible on the terminal. And this could have been a *long* rabbit hole of debugging...)

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem (on Windows).  I ended up checking my `~/.gitconfig` file and found that my `excludesfile` was set to:

```
excludesfile = C:\\Users\\myUserName\\Documents\\gitignore_global.txt
```

but it should have been:

```
excludesfile = C:\\Users\\myUserName\\.gitignore_global
```

After I changed it, everything worked as it should.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when using Cygwin with Windows Git. I had forgotten to include Git from Cygwin. When I added Git to my Cygwin software base, the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

Another hard to track reason why .gitignore(_global) appears not working could be leading spaces in the lines. The file is not forgiving for leading spaces. So make sure each line of your file doesn't have any unless it's blank line. It took me a while to figure out.

Just adding my two cents.

Answer (score 0):

I recently made a mistake and run the following command
`git config core.excludesfile tags`
this changed the excludesfile path to a local file in the current repository, and this config has been written to the local config file under `.git/config`, so to fix that I just opened the `.git/config` file and deleted the line `excludesfile tags` and everything is back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

A problem I was running into is that I tried putting INLINE comments in my global git ignore.

For example this does NOT work:

```
.DS_Store   # from macOS Finder
```

This DOES work:

```
# from macOS Finder
.DS_Store
```

Answer (score 0):

after adding directory / filename to .gitignore, you should delete those files and/or directories and recreate them.

This worked for me. Hope works for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when using [GitKraken](https://www.gitkraken.com/) on an Ubuntu Desktop.  The approved answer above (`git config --global core.excludesFile ~/.gitignore_global`) didn't work for me, because `git` in my `$PATH` points to `/usr/bin/git`.

GitKraken has a setting to determine which git binary to use and by default will choose the one it ships with (not `/usr/bin/git`.  Finding its binary is a little more difficult.

```
find /snap/gitkraken/ -name 'git' -type f
```

Gives

```
/snap/gitkraken/226/usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/git/bin/git
/snap/gitkraken/226/usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/git/libexec/git-core/git
```

And then doing

```
/snap/gitkraken/226/usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/git/bin/git config --global core.excludesFile $HOME/.gitignore-global
```

Fixed my problem