# Unable to ignore .idea file via .gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

I pushed my code without putting `.idea/` in .gitignore. But now when I realised it, I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9550437/how-to-make-git-ignore-idea-files-created-by-rubymine) SO answer. So when I tried to undo that commit/push using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1270608/1291122) SO answer, it works. But after adding `.idea/*` to .gitignore, and then doing git add and pushing the code, the .idea directory appears again and I can see all my previous commits(which I did undo).

What to do now?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It appears again because you didn't ignore the `.idea` folder. You ignored the `.idea` folder *content*.

To ignore the whole folder, your `.gitignore` should contain:

```
.idea/
```

If the `.idea` folder remains, I would suggests removing it from the index (not from the disk with the `--cached` option) and pushing a new commit recording that deletion:

```
git rm --cached -r .idea/
git add -A .
git commit -m "Delete .idea"
git push
```

Comment: Thanks @VonC. But I tried this too before idea/*. The problem looks like that although i undid my previous commit from remote, but its still there in my local repo. This commit contains the idea folder. So unless this commit is erased, successive pushes would push this one also, thereby pushing the idea folder.