# How to ignore .idea folder and all its contents in Rubymine when it's never been tracked?

Tags: gitignore, rubymine

I'm trying to ignore the .idea/ folder created by Rubymine by default as not everyone in this project is using this IDE, but I can't seem to achieve it.

So far I've tried to ignore it from the gitignore_global, as I won't be commiting this folder in any of my projects; and also from Rubymine settings as shown below, but not of them seem to be working. Maybe I'm not using the correct line in the gitignore?

My gitignore_global has only one line: `.idea/`

It is properly configured as I can see this on the .gitconfig file (and the path matches):

```
[core]
    excludesfile = C:\\Users\\izamudio\\.gitignore_global
```

I have also tried adding the folder to Rubymine Ignored Files as "Ignore all files under" and selecting the folder path.

I expect the file to not show on the untracked files when I use the git status command in the rubymine terminal, but I keep getting:

```
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        .idea/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Am I missing something here? Is it being ignored but the rubymine terminal is showing me otherwise?

I've also tried `**/.idea/` and `.idea/*` but neither of this options seems to do the job.

IMPORTANT EDIT:
After some help from JetBrains support I realized I had my path wrongly configured. The gitignore_global file was missing the dot at the beginning for some reason, so the path in the .gitconfig was not correct. After changing the name of the file from gitignore_global to .gitingore_global everything is working properly.

Comment: Hello! There's a similar SO thread, could you please check it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9550437/how-to-make-git-ignore-idea-files-created-by-rubymine

Comment: Hello Olivia, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately the problem is a little bit different from that one, as my directory has not ever been tracked but refuses to be ignored. Running ```git rm -r --cached .idea``` gives me ```fatal: pathspec '.idea' did not match any files```, which makes sense because it's never been tracked. So what's happening here is totally different from that issue, I think.

Comment: Is your .gitignore in the project's root?

Comment: Hello again. The problem was that the file .gitignore_global was missing the dot at the beginning, so it was not being detected. The JetBrains support pointed me in the good direction when I reached them and confirmed that .idea/ is the correct pattern. It's working already.