# I can't stop tracking files in source Tree

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree, sourcetree

I added to my repository files that I don't want to track now. I don't want them to appear in this pending files window but I don't wont to delete them from the project. The problem is that I don't know how to fix it. I tried everything. I even deleted them from repository(but not from the project so they were still on my disk) but after it they appeared in deleted files. It is really annoying. So how to get rid of this `/target/` files.

Warning: Stop tracking option dosen't work! There is no reaction on it.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I stop Git from tracking any changes to a file from this commit forward?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18276951/how-do-i-stop-git-from-tracking-any-changes-to-a-file-from-this-commit-forward)

Answer (score 12):

Here is an answer in [Atlassian answers](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/39785117/stop-tracking-doesnt-do-anything)

It is said there that:
The issue seems to be that the cancel and Okay button functionality is switched up for that option.  Hitting cancel actually made it stop tracking the file(s).

It worked for me also. Version 1.9.6.1

Answer (score 4):

Here is simple solution ,Add the file name or folder with to your .gitignore,then git will ignore it on source change.

```
filename_with_path or folder
```

and you can use `git rm -r filename/folder*` to ignore it for ever

Comment: are using UI or gitbash? use this commands on gitbash "git clean -f" will remove the untracked files from your source tree!