# Adding several items to .gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a project with a layout like this:

```
folder_a
    folder_b
       file1.html
       file2.html
    folder_c
       file3.html
       file4.html
    folder_d
    .gitignore
```

Now, my goal is to include `file3.html` and the entire contents of `folder_a/folder_b` to .gitignore. To achieve this, I have written the following in .gitignore:

```
folder_b/
folder_c/file3.html
```

This seems elementary, and yet it doesn't work for me. The data still gets updated. What am I doing wrong? I've read the [doc](https://ru.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes/gitignore), and now it seems like I should write the full path, is it true? I am stuck.

Comment: Where is the git repo? The .gitignore file needs to be in the root folder, I think.

Comment: Did you `git init` in `folder_a`?

Comment: Dennis, yes, I did. This is an existing git project

Comment: You wrote that your goal is to "include" the files that you have listed in `.gitignore`. Do you mean "exclude"? What you have looks correct if your goal is to exclude.

Comment: Well, my goal is to INCLUDE them to .gitignore, that is, to EXCLUDE them from the files that are being synced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of `.gitignore` is to exclude files from version control, not to prevent changes to files that are already in version control. Make sure that the files that you want to exclude are not in version control. You can do that without deleting the files on disk with commands like this:

```
git rm --cached folder_c/file3.html
```

And then commit the result.

Edit: It seems that OP wants to ignore new changes to files that are in version control. For that case there is a relevant answer on this question: [How do I stop Git from tracking any changes to a file from this commit forward?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18276951/how-do-i-stop-git-from-tracking-any-changes-to-a-file-from-this-commit-forward)

Comment: my goal is to to prevent changes, but I need the files to be present in the bitbucket

Comment: In that case I think you want to use the answer from this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18276951/how-do-i-stop-git-from-tracking-any-changes-to-a-file-from-this-commit-forward