# Why git can see some ignored files?

Tags: git, netbeans, gitignore

I'm trying to versioning a Netbeans Project. So I keep in my remote repo:

- [projectname]/src
- [projectname]/nbproject

The point is that I don't want to update nbproject files after every build/commit. Updating the properties is necessary only when I make big changes, like adding a new library (in all other cases cloning the project with the same old folder work).
At first I pushed a commit with the 2 working directories, after that I modified and committed the .gitignore adding /nbproject , so the others can clone the project without references/properties problems and commit source changes without updating the nbproject files.
The idea of my team is that every time there is a big change to do (like adding a new library to the project), the commit should be done manually from git bash forcing the nbproject folder to update, in all other cases instead (most of the times) it can be safely done using NetBeans changing and committing only the source.

The problem is occured when I needed to add a library. Infact after the addition of the .jar and code changes I went to check what git saw from bash, this is the output of `git status`:

```
    $ git status
# On branch newVersioning
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working dire
#
#       modified:   ****/nbproject/project.properties
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       lib/**************.jar
#       ****/src/***/***********/****.java

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

I don't understand why git can see (without any type of forcing) the change of the file project.properties that it should automatically ignored by versioning.
This is the .gitignore line

```
****/nbproject/
```

Comment: gitignore only works in the directory it is in, so in nbproject/ add an .gitignore with *

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried your suggestion but doesn't work.

Comment: then you did something wrong... this will work with all files unknown to git, if you already added the file, then git will show you the change of it regardless of the gitignore

Comment: The funny thing is that adding a new ".gitignore" in the nbproject folder is not seen from git, change project.properties building the project with a new library still yes!
It seems that good guy git would notice that without adding to commit that file the project stopped working.

Comment: this becouse of the * which includes the .gitignore file to. i bet the file you seeing are already added/comited to git.

Comment: no, i cloned a virgin repo, after that, at first I added the ".gitignore" to the nbproject folder and after added the new library and re-built the project.

Comment: whats in your .gitignore?

Comment: [projectname]/nbproject/
[projectname]/build/
[projectname]/dist/
[projectname]/log/*

Comment: no. add the file [projectname]/nbproject/.gitignore and only add `*` into it.

Comment: I already added that file in that path.
It doesn't solved. The list below was of the root .gitignore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.gitignore` only works for untracked files. Your `project.properties` file has already been added and committed to your Git repository, so it will not be ignored.

[See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10755655/git-ignore-tracked-files) for a way to work around this limitation.