# Removing previously tracked files from git repo without deleting them on pull

Tags: git

I have a few files that I'd like to stop tracking in my git repository, but which I don't want to actually delete.  `git -rm --cached` works well locally, but will still delete the files when someone else pulls the changes.

Is there a way to stop tracking a previously tracked file without deleting it on my machine OR from the machine anyone else who pulls the changes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git: Ignore tracked files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10755655/git-ignore-tracked-files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tell git to ignore further changes with

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <file name>
```

https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-update-index.html

http://blog.pagebakers.nl/2009/01/29/git-ignoring-changes-in-tracked-files/

Comment: Thanks.  This seems like a kind of ugly solution but it does solve my problem.