# Prevent config-file from showing up as modified in git after commiting it once

Tags: git

I commited a basic version (without passwords etc.) of my config-file to a git repo. Now I want it to not show up below "changes not staged for commit" as modified anymore so I can just use `git add *` without worrying that I commit my user-data.

Adding the file in question to .gitignore didn't help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git: Ignore tracked files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10755655/git-ignore-tracked-files). The short answer is "don't do that" (both trying to get git to ignore modified files; and `git add *`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `git update-index --assume-unchanged <path>`.

But it's important to note, that a hard reset will revert this (`stash` for example makes a hard reset).