# Ask git to ignore some uncommitted changes so that they are not displayed in the list of uncommitted changes

Tags: git, ignore

I have a few changes which I don't want to commit and yet I want to retain them locally. Problem is that I use git (with git status), they keep appearing in the list of uncommitted changes. I want to ask git to ignore such changes and yet retain them locally.

I can't discard them since I want the changes to be retained locally.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git: Ignore tracked files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10755655/git-ignore-tracked-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know, how you can ignore exactly *specific changes*. But you can ignore changes in tracking files. And when you want to commit some another changes, you can make file unignored, commit necessary changes and make other file changes ignored again.

You can do it by using `git update-index --assume_unchanged <file>` (see [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-update-index.html#_using_8220_assume_unchanged_8221_bit))

To start tracking changes again use `git update-index --no-assume_unchanged <file>`

To show ignoring files use `git ls-files -v`

Comment: This has changed to `git update-index --[no-]assume-unchanged` as of git 2.9 I believe.