# Ignore changes to a tracked file

Tags: git, file, ignore

I want to change a tracked file for development only, but keep the tracked version unchanged.

Most "solutions" for this suggest

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged
```

but it's totally useless, because the file will still be changed by checkout or reset. Is there a better solution that survives checkout and reset commands?

Comment: I *think* you could `.gitignore` it in your development branch. Then again, this smells funny - are you sure you haven't committed what's for all intents and purpouses a configuration file? :)

Comment: A `checkout` will not undo your changes. At worst, Git will tell you that a possible merge conflict will occur during pulls and checkouts. A `reset` will certainly stomp on your changes. Why not create a topic branch where you edit the file and commit those changes?

Comment: Read this: https://gist.github.com/canton7/1423106 (found via http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10755655/git-ignore-tracked-files)

Comment: .gitignore seems to do nothing once the file is added. It only stops untracked files. Yes, it's a config file and I want to keep the upstream version intact.

Comment: Which branch are you working in? master, development, a topic branch?

Comment: @LarryShatzer Thanks for the link, but it only confirms that git has no good solution for this. A lot of needlessly complicated workarounds for something that should be base functionality. Why even have "assume unchanged" at all when it breaks so easily?

Comment: @GregBurghardt There's only a master branch. And yes, "checkout -- ." will undo changes in a "assume-unchanged" file.

Comment: @user923487: A checkout will not undo changes. Git should warn you that it cannot switch branches with changes to that file. I routinely make changes to our application config files after using the `update-index` command on them. The changes persist between branches, and checkouts that would result in a merge conflict are blocked.

Comment: @GregBurghardt I tested it right now. Made my changes to the file, set it to "assume-unchanged". It disappears from the changed files in git status, but "checkout -- ." still undoes the changes.

Comment: Ok. So `checkout` doesn't mean "switch branches" in your case. Yes, a `checkout -- X` will remove those changes.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## Quick Fix

This is what I think you're trying to do, change a file, but ignore it when committing.

```bash
git update-index --skip-worktree my-file
```

Here is a good answer regarding the [difference between `assume-unchanged` and `skip-worktree`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13631525/4231110).

Git will still warn if you try to merge changes into `my-file`. Then you will have to "unskip" the file, merge it and "re-skip" it.

```bash
git update-index --no-skip-worktree my-file
# merge here
git update-index --skip-worktree my-file
```

There can also be problems if you modify the file, then switch to a branch where that file has been changed. You may have to do some fancy "skip/unskip" operations to get around that.

## Long Term Fix

In the long term, you probably want to separate your "local" changes into a second file. For example, if the file you want to change is a config file, create a "default" config file that you check into the repository. Then, allow a second "overrides" config file that is optional and put that file in your `.gitignore`.

Then, in your application, read the default config file and then check if the overrides file exists. If it does, merge that data with the data from the default file.

This example is for a config file, but you can use that technique for other kinds of overrides if needed.

Comment: --skip-worktree is exactly what I was looking for, according to the description. Thank you. Modifying the project to make this work seems wrong to me.

Answer (score 1):

Since in one of your comments you are working directly in the `master` branch, the real problem to fix is working in `master`.

You'll want to create a Topic Branch in Git:

```
git checkout -b some_feature_or_bug_fix master
```

Then make the necessary changes to the config file, and commit as normal.

The nice thing here is you don't affect files in `master`. If you need to pull in updated code, just `git fetch` and `git merge origin/master` into your topic branch. Then you can deal with upstream changes to the config file as normal Git merges.

Prior to merging your topic branch into `master` you can do an interactive squash to reduce your commits and merge commits into one nice, clean commit. Or do a `git merge --squash` to merge your topic branch into `master`.