# Adding new entries to .gitignore doesn't work

Tags: git

If I understand right, in order to "ignore" a file so it won't come up when I type `git status` or `git add -A` I need to add it to the .gitignore file.

My goal is to ignore a certain folder and file when committing changes to Git, permanently.

I tried editing the .gitignore file in my editor:

```
config/
src/package.xml
```

I saved the file, committed and pushed to Git, refreshed my project from another repository, typed `git status` and still saw the xml file and the folder.

Also tried using GItHub Desktop by choosing "Discard Changes", it automatically added to .gitignore the following lines:

```
*.sublime-workspace
config/.local_store
*.sublime-workspace
src/package.xml
```

but same result...

**Project Structure:**

```
          Full
    ________|____________
   |        |            |
config  .gitignore      src
   |                     |
  ...                package.xml
```

Comment: If the file had already been added to the repo, it will need to be removed before the .gitignore will ignore it.

Comment: If you downvote a question, add a comment to explain why

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ignore files that have already been committed to a Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/ignore-files-that-have-already-been-committed-to-a-git-repository)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`.gitignore` doesn't apply retroactively. It is read by `git add` only when a file is added for the first time to the repo.

If the file is already in the repo, listing it in `gitignore` is not enough. You also need to remove it from the repo (`git rm --cached src/package.xml`).

Don't forget to `git add .gitignore` and `git commit`, in order to persist the changes.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that I have to delete the folder/file from Git in order to ignore them. just one thing, I had to add -r to the remove command:

 
git rm -r --cached src/package.xml

Comment: It is explained in the first paragraph of the documentation of [`.gitignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore): *"A `gitignore` file specifies intentionally untracked files that Git should ignore. Files already tracked by Git are not affected."*. Also available on your computer using `git help gitignore`.

Answer (score 0):

If your XML file is already tracked and you want to keep it, you can ignore the new modifications with the command described in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10755704/6162120). Otherwise you will have to remove it as mentioned in the comments.

Note that an alternative to `.gitignore` is to use `.git/info/exclude`.