# Git: show "assumed unchanged" files

Tags: git

After doing `update-index --assume-unchanged` as answered in [Stackoverflow: Ignore Tracked file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10755655/git-ignore-tracked-files), how can I list those files?

I have done that on many files and now I need a list so that I can undo the effect...

Comment: You should be using `--skip-worktree` instead of `--assume-unchanged`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+list+assume-unchanged

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> To see which files have the "assume unchanged" bit set, use git
>   ls-files -v.

See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#_using_assume_unchanged_bit.

A lowercase `h` indicates the file has "assume unchanged" bit set.

```
git ls-files -v | grep ^h
```

For other statuses, see the option [-t](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files#git-ls-files--t).