# How to ignore Xcode merge backup files?

Tags: xcode, git, git-merge

In Xcode, after `git mergetool`, there are some backup files like this:

```
X.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj.BACKUP.36127.pbxproj
X.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj.LOCAL.36127.pbxproj
X.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj.REMOTE.36127.pbxproj
```

How to ignore these files in git with `.gitignore`?

Thanks.

Comment: Just remove them after merge is done

Comment: @Vladimir yes, I can remove them after merge. Is there any way to ignore these files in .gitignore?

Comment: Add `X.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj.*.*.pbxproj`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in [this article](http://portal.customerfx.com/wikis/devguidelines/using-the-gitignore-file-with-saleslogix-models.aspx), you could add in your [global ignore file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7529266/6309):

```
*.BACKUP.*.pbxproj
*.BASE.*.pbxproj
*.LOCAL.*.pbxproj
```

Strangely enough, there isn't yet an XCode file in the ["GitHub Ignore" global files project](https://github.com/github/gitignore/tree/master/Global).

[indiantroy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/412678/indiantroy) [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5249925) also ignoring:

```
*.REMOTE.*.pbxproj
```