# .gitignore_global is not working, even .gitconfig shows the .gitignore_global

Tags: git

I created the `.gitignore_global` file and save it to the directory where i have `.gitconfig` file.

After then, i used this command.

```
git config --global core.excludesfile .gitignore_global
```

then i checked my .gitconfig file by using the command

```
cat .gitconfig
```

It shows me result as

```
[user]
        email = hemant.parihar264@gmail.com
        name = Hemant Parihar
[gui]
        recentrepo = C:/Users/heman/gitprojects
        recentrepo = E:/Inspiration/developerquery
[filter "lfs"]
        clean = git-lfs clean %f
        smudge = git-lfs smudge %f
        required = true
[core]
        excludesfile = .gitignore_global
```

It clear shows me in **[core]** section, there is `.gitignore file`.
But in my project repository i created a file which should be ignored as i configure the .gitignore_global. But that should not happen. But when i used local .gitignore file to my project, it works fine and ignore the files which should not be tracked.

My project repository directory is ***E:/Inspiration/server/explore_california*** while ***.gitignore_global*** is in my home directory (where .gitconfig file is present.).

I checked [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7529266/git-global-ignore-not-working) but i did not find anything that is helpful.

Comment: Any particular reason to not use local .gitignore file?

Comment: I just want to assign this rule to all my repository. Also when i used local .gitignore file it works very well.

Comment: Not a good idea for teamwork though. They'll have local .gitignore but not your global one. Please use it carefully. Maybe what you are looking for is putting ~/ in front of your .gitignore_global record in .gitconfig file: `excludesfile = ~/.gitignore_global`

Comment: Thanks it all about this ~/ .

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The path to the global gitignore needs to be absolute, so you could use the shell expansion here and just specify it as `~/.gitignore_global`:

```
git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global
```

---

In order to understand what’s going on if you don’t use an absolute path, you have to understand how git configs work: Every repository has one in `.git/config`. In addition, there is the global `~/.gitconfig`. Configuration values from both places are merged (with the local repository settings taking precedence in case of conflicts) to produce a single set of configuation settings. You can inspect those by running `git config -l` inside a local repository.

So configuration is always local to the current repository. So when you have a relative path to a “global” excludesfile, that path is interpreted relatively to your repository.

So with `excludesfile = .gitignore_global`, Git would look into your *local repository* for a file `gitignore_global`. And it would use that as well as the normal `.gitignore` and the repository’s `.git/info/exclude`.

So you could actually place a `.gitignore_global` file into every repository and Git would pick it up.

So since you want a global configuration, you need to specify an absolute path.

Comment: yup. It is working. but i want to know why it is not working. git config --global core.excludesfile .gitignore_global

Comment: @HemantParihar Added more explanation about why an absolute path is necessary.