# git two dashes means with no more options

Tags: git, version-control, github

I am learning the `try git by code school`, and to the unit 1.17 Undo it use the command line

```
git checkout -- octocat.txt
```

and the octocat.txt is a file then and it explain that the two dash lines is

> It's simply promising the command line that there are no more options
>   after the '--'.  This way if you happen to have a branch named
>   octocat.txt,  it will still revert the file,  instead of switching to
>   the branch of the same name.

but what I cannot understand is that what does it means by no options?
And since there are no options after, why it can distinguish it by file from branch?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`--` means stop processing options, and even if something does look like an option, e.g. `--help`, it should be treated as usual parameter, like file name instead.

Using this syntax, you can actually add or remove file which is called say `--help`, which would be impossible otherwise.

In git syntax, `--` is also usually used to specify affected files. For example, `git checkout something` could mean either checkout branch named `something` or file called `something`. If you use `git checkout -- something`, it always means file, not branch.