# git reset <file> versus git reset -- <file>

Tags: git

I need to add several files to group them into a single commit, but I have to exclude one of them. In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4475506/1391441), the code given to do this is:

```
git add -u
git reset -- file_to_ignore.dat
```

I'm not sure what the dashes do in the last command. What is the difference with the following?

```
git reset file_to_ignore.dat
```

which is how it's shown in [this tutorial](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/undoing-changes/git-reset).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I mentioned that double hyphen (or double dash) notation in "[Deleting a badly named git branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1192194/6309)".

It helps separating the options of a commands from the actual arguments (filename)

> It is also conventional to recognize a double hyphen as a signal to stop option interpretation and treat all following arguments literally.

In your case, there is no difference... unless the file name is '`master`'! (in which case, the `--` are very important)

Comment: Great answer VonC, you make very clear when the dashes are important. Thank you!