# Git add all modified files with some exceptions

Tags: git, git-add

With git I would like to add (almost) all the modified files, in practice those marked with the letter ***M*** in VScode, but I would like to add exceptions, that is, not to consider one or two files.

Is there a generic way to say to add all the changes except one or two files?

Comment: Yes, add each and every file you actually want to commit.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51914162/10155936

Comment: what if there are too many files then it becomes difficult to add individual files then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59679018/12668430) will be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be better off adding everything then unstaging the ones you don't want :

```
git add -u
git reset -- path/to/file1 path/to/file2
```

Comment: Why would you use `git add .` instead of `git add -u`?

Comment: generally `-u` is used to detect changed files. Let say you have changed a file and created a new file. git will only recognize the file change but not the new file. by giving `-u` it recognizes new file entries too

Comment: @Memmo git add . is to add all files including those which are not been tracked, git add -u is to add all the files which are tracked.

Comment: Exact! It was what I wanted. Edited files only (_**M**_ in VScode)

Comment: @Memmo I didn't get that you wanted to (re)add each file, I took it as "every modified file", but yes, `-u` is the right tool to update every known path.

Answer (score 0):

Add the two/three files to the `.gitignore` and push all the changes. By default git ignores those two files, so that exemptions are ignored. After the `push` remove the files from `.gitignore`. This hack will definitely work.