# How can I deploy a project without changing a file which is on heroku hosting?

Tags: python, git, heroku

I made an application. And the application has a .json file. Many data stores in this file. So, when I git clone the project, edit it, and publish it, it overwrites the existing data on the .json file. So, how can I deploy the whole project without the .json file?

Comment: Should .json file be even included in the project files? I think it should be in gitignore.

Comment: [Your question already has an answer here! Hope this helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475457/add-all-files-to-a-commit-except-a-single-file)